# how do I separate two strings in python that have been printed using functions?

Tags: string, python-3.x, newline

I have created a function to print out a string with a timed delay between each character but when it comes to printing multiple strings, they are all printed on the same line. How would I separate the lines? (`'\n'` does not work)

```
from time import sleep
import sys

def slowly(text):
    for letters in text:
        print (letters, end=''),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.1)
        if letters == ',':
            sleep(1)

slowly("hello world")
slowly("hello world")
```

Result

```
"hello worldhello world"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline to the function after the loop, like

```
from time import sleep

def slowly(text):
    for letter in text:
        print(letter, end = '')
        sleep(0.1)
        if letter == ',':
            sleep(1)
    print()    # Print a newline

slowly('hello world')
slowly('hello world')
```

This works for me.

**Output**

```
hello world
hello world
```